# Ruby does not escape oct on puts

Tags: ruby, string, octal

I have a script that parses a large text file, extracts certain values (using line.split), and stores them in a text file.  I am having problems with octal values not interpreting when they are saved to the file.

When I manually specify the `string` of `oct` characters, it works fine:

```
test = "\320\232\320\250\320\220"

puts test
```

However, if I get the string above using `title = line.split('=')[1]`, the string value is identical, yet when I attempt to `puts`, it simply re-states the entire string (including quotes)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure where the `split` is coming from. Are you trying to parse your actual Ruby source code? In that case, you'll need to do something to interpret the escape sequences. A trivial (but less-than-ideal) way would be to `eval` it, but it really depends what your goal is.

Comment: I am parsing a string out of a large text file I am searching.  I am very new to Ruby (as you can tell).   At times values I am collecting will include oct character codes, and at times may consiste entirely out of them.  How do I use the eval?

Comment: `eval` is only appropriate if your goal is to evaluate Ruby expressions. If these are simply untrusted strings with escape sequences, you'll need a method that can unescape them. PHP has some built-in; looks like you'll need to write or find one in Ruby that supports whatever escape sequences your strings may contain.

Comment: But how come if I provide the string of octal values by directly assigning them to a string variable, they work fine?

Comment: See my answer for the answer to this question.

Answer (score 2):

@xaxxon has explained why your octal codes aren't being converted when you read the string from a file instead of presenting them as ruby literals.  Here's a simple method that will convert octal \xxx encoding substrings to the appropriate ascii character.

```
def octal_convert(s)
  s.gsub(/\\(?:\\|[0-7]{3})/) do |capture|
    capture == "\\\\" ?
      "\\" :
      capture[1,3].to_i(8).chr
  end
end

test = 'ab\\\\cd\320\232\320\250\320\220'
=> "ab\\\\cd\\320\\232\\320\\250\\320\\220"
octal_convert(test)
=> "ab\\cd\xD0\x9A\xD0\xA8\xD0\x90"
```

Comment: very nice :)  "Fairly complicated" is in the eye of the beholder, I suppose.

Comment: exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

When a literal string is encountered in ruby source code, the ruby interpreter will look at the string and perform certain escapes, such as the octal you have specified.  Same thing if you put a newline in a string with "\n".

However, when you're reading data from a file, that interpolation does not happen.  If you want to do that, you would have to do the logic for finding and changing the values yourself using string search or regular expressions.

Ideally the file you're reading wouldn't have octal-escape-looking text in it, it would just have the actual value right in the file.  This will get rid of the need for some fairly complicated text parsing and allow you to read the file as you expect.